# IntelliJ 13 shows errors on maven plugins

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-plugin

Opening a maven project with IntelliJ 13, the plugin folder of each subproject shows the errors that can be see in the picture.

[image: Plugins folder]

This is the log:

```
2013-12-13 14:55:37,477 [ 180923]   INFO -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - error in opening zip file 
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:159)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.utils.MavenArtifactUtil.createPluginDocument(MavenArtifactUtil.java:155)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.utils.MavenArtifactUtil.readPluginInfo(MavenArtifactUtil.java:50)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.navigator.MavenProjectsStructure$PluginNode.updatePlugin(MavenProjectsStructure.java:1070)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.navigator.MavenProjectsStructure$PluginNode.<init>(MavenProjectsStructure.java:1050)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.navigator.MavenProjectsStructure$PluginsNode.updatePlugins(MavenProjectsStructure.java:1023)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.navigator.MavenProjectsStructure$ProjectNode.updateProject(MavenProjectsStructure.java:705)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.navigator.MavenProjectsStructure$ProjectNode.access$000(MavenProjectsStructure.java:655)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.navigator.MavenProjectsStructure.doUpdateProject(MavenProjectsStructure.java:195)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.navigator.MavenProjectsStructure.updateProjects(MavenProjectsStructure.java:166)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.navigator.MavenProjectsNavigator$MyProjectsListener$3.run(MavenProjectsNavigator.java:455)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.navigator.MavenProjectsNavigator$11.run(MavenProjectsNavigator.java:378)
    at com.intellij.util.DisposeAwareRunnable.run(DisposeAwareRunnable.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:346)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.e(IdeEventQueue.java:696)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:524)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

In any case the build maven works.

No issue found on http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

What's going?

Comment: Some files in your local Maven repository may be corrupted. You can try removing them and then running `mvn install` again for this project so that all the dependencies are downloaded. If it doesn't help, file a bug to YouTrack with a sample project to reproduce.

Comment: You are right. My repository is corrupt. The problem is that it is intellij, in some way, to corrupt it because, if I delete the .m2 dir. and do an install from the command line, everything works fine.
If I do it via intellij, I get the jar files corrupted!

Comment: I found that the corrupted jar files that intellij downloaded is actually an html file that contains the following: `<title>302 Found</title>` `The document has moved` In addition there is a open issue that is related to this problem: youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118263

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed in version 13.1 (135 475) as reported at the following link:

From: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-120840

> The bundled version of Maven, 3.0.3, in the maven plugin has a bug
>   that causes it to save the body of redirect responses from the remote
>   repository as the requested artifact, rather than following the
>   redirect.  This results in large numbers of jar and XML files being
>   saved to the local (~/.m2/repository) repo with invalid content
>   (typically an HTML file), causing all builds that use those artifacts
>   to fail.  This bug was fixed with the update to the Maven Wagon plugin
>   in Maven 3.0.5...